# CentOS qpidd default network service

Tags: centos6

I just did a clean minimal net install of Cent OS 6.  I did a netstat just to see what was listening:

```
tcp    0  0 127.0.0.1:25    0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      1165/master
tcp    0  0 0.0.0.0:5672    0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      1178/qpidd
```

Besides ssh, I also see qpidd and what looks to be mail on localhost.  I tried to google around to see what these were and why they were running by default on the minimal install. If possible I want to disable these as I am trying to go very very minimal with this.

Answer (score 1):

if you lookup port 5672 in /etc/services, you will find that is assigned to [AMQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol):

I suspect one of the applications installed has a dependency on AMQP (Here is my SL install as a reference point):

```
No Matches found
[root@kerberos bin]# yum search amqp
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
=============================================================================================================== N/S Matched: amqp ================================================================================================================
matahari-broker.x86_64 : Optional AMQP Broker for Matahari
mingw32-qpid-cpp.noarch : MinGW Windows port of AMQP C++ Daemons and Libraries
python-qpid.noarch : Python client library for AMQP
qpid-cpp-client-devel-docs.noarch : AMQP client development documentation
qpid-cpp-server.i686 : An AMQP message broker daemon
qpid-cpp-server.x86_64 : An AMQP message broker daemon
ruby-qpid.x86_64 : Ruby language client for AMQP

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
[root@kerberos bin]# yum search qpid
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
=============================================================================================================== N/S Matched: qpid ================================================================================================================
fence-virtd-libvirt-qpid.x86_64 : Libvirt-qpid backend for fence-virtd
libvirt-qpid.x86_64 : QPid QMF interface to Libvirt
python-qpid-qmf.x86_64 : Python QMF library for Apache Qpid
qpid-cpp-client.i686 : Libraries for Qpid C++ client applications
qpid-cpp-client.x86_64 : Libraries for Qpid C++ client applications
qpid-cpp-client-devel.x86_64 : Header files, documentation and testing tools for developing Qpid C++ clients
qpid-cpp-client-rdma.x86_64 : RDMA Protocol support (including Infiniband) for Qpid clients
qpid-cpp-client-ssl.i686 : SSL support for Qpid clients
qpid-cpp-client-ssl.x86_64 : SSL support for Qpid clients
qpid-cpp-server-cluster.x86_64 : Cluster support for the Qpid daemon
qpid-cpp-server-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and header files for developing Qpid broker extensions
qpid-cpp-server-rdma.x86_64 : RDMA Protocol support (including Infiniband) for the Qpid daemon
qpid-cpp-server-ssl.x86_64 : SSL support for the Qpid daemon
qpid-cpp-server-store.x86_64 : Red Hat persistence extension to the Qpid messaging system
qpid-cpp-server-xml.x86_64 : XML extensions for the Qpid daemon
qpid-qmf.i686 : The Qpid Management Framework
qpid-qmf.x86_64 : The Qpid Management Framework
qpid-tests.noarch : Conformance tests for Apache Qpid
qpid-tools.noarch : Management and diagnostic tools for Apache Qpid
ruby-qpid-qmf.i686 : The QPID Management Framework bindings for ruby
ruby-qpid-qmf.x86_64 : The QPID Management Framework bindings for ruby
mingw32-qpid-cpp.noarch : MinGW Windows port of AMQP C++ Daemons and Libraries
python-qmf.noarch : Python QMF library for Apache Qpid
python-qpid.noarch : Python client library for AMQP
qpid-cpp-client-devel-docs.noarch : AMQP client development documentation
qpid-cpp-server.i686 : An AMQP message broker daemon
qpid-cpp-server.x86_64 : An AMQP message broker daemon
qpid-qmf-devel.x86_64 : Header files and tools for developing QMF extensions
rh-qpid-cpp-tests.x86_64 : Internal Red Hat test utilities
ruby-qpid.x86_64 : Ruby language client for AMQP
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking through package dependencies, it seems like qpidd is used by [Matahari](https://github.com/matahari/matahari/wiki), some sort of management framework. I haven't tried it (yet), but, I guess you can safely disable/uninstall it, if you are not going to use those remote management capabilities.

Comment: Openstack uses it qpid too. https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/QpidSupport

Answer (score 0):

This particular daemon comes from the `qpid-cpp-server` package shipped with EL6. This is [Apache Qpid](http://qpid.apache.org), an implementation of [Advanced Message Queuing Protocol](http://www.amqp.org/). Interestingly, none of my CentOS installations had this particular package installed, though I did my installations using CentOS install CD. Are you sure you did an actual "minimal" installation, or did you install a virtual server based on someone's "minimal" (so they claim) template? Perhaps someone's pre-made [EC2 AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/amis/)?

The other item listening on localhost port 25 is postfix. In its default installation, it only listens for mail orginating from the system, and cannot receive mail from the network. It's generally safe to leave it in that configuration, though you may want to set it up to forward all server-generated mail to some other email address, so that you actually receive it somewhere convenient.